# how to prevent an activity "relaunched" automatically?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm new to android and would appreciate any help

I have several activities on my app. From splash screen i launch my main activity (ChooseActivity). In ChooseActivity i have 2 buttons to launch 2 differents activities (A and B). The problem are while i am on activity A or B, the application goes/"relaunched"/or bring to front the activity ChooseActivity, at randomly (some times at few seconds, some times at few minutes). I want to prevent this, i only want to return at ChooseActivity when i want (pressing button on screen for example)

Activities A or B shows some popups that i can close from a button on screen o pressing phone's back button, but Activites A or B can’t close pressing phone's back button (I disabled this option)

I've tried the options proposed in different threads, but without result

This is my manifest:

```
<activity
  android:name=".SplashScreen"
  android:launchMode="singleInstance"
  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
  android:name=".A"
  android:launchMode="singleInstance"
  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
<activity
  android:name=".B"
  android:launchMode="singleInstance"
  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
```

Opening ChooseActivity from SplashScreen:

```
public void closeSplash()
{
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ChooseActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```

Opening A activity from ChooseActivity:

```
private void goA()
{
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), A.class);
    startActivity(i); 
    finish();       
}
```

A.java:

```
...
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
}
...
```

I would greatly appreciate any help or indication

Thank you

Comment: you have to put intent in button click not in onCreate so when button clicks it redirect

Comment: share activity A all code....

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly. I think @Pritesh Vadhiya points in the right direction. In "onCreate()" of my Splash screen, after some animation and some delay i call the method "closeSplash()" (touching on any part of the screen is also called the same method, and I did not wait at the end of the animation, I was directly touching the screen). Removing this call from "onCreate()" seems to work. I have to do more tests, because as I said, sometimes it was produced in a few seconds and sometimes in a few minutes. I will post the results after testing. Thanks

Comment: @Hern welcome hern ;)

Comment: @Pritesh Vadhiya After more exhaustive tests the problem has not been reproduced again. I give the problem solved. Thank you very much Pritesh Vadhiya

Answer (score 0):

Don't finish ChooseActivity  in goA() method

```
private void goA()
{
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), A.class);
startActivity(i); 
 // finish(); its finished ChooseActivity remove it    
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, sasikumar, but i tried with o without "finish()" with no result